# Update an existing file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I write this code to write data in a text file.

```
 Writer output = null;
   File file = new File("C:/HEADER.txt");
   output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    output.write("hello");
    output.close();
```

I write this code to write over the file but what happened is that the data got deleted, and the only the new data appeared.

```
Writer output = null;
   File file = new File("C:/HEADER.txt");
   output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    output.write("how are you");
    output.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
new FileWriter(file, true)
```

this will open the file in append mode

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Writer output = null;
File file = new File("C:/HEADER.txt");
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
output.write("how are you");
output.close();
```

`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)` constructs a `FileWriter` object given a `File` object. If the second argument is `true`, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

reference : [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write like

```
File f = new File ("C:/HEADER.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true); 
//mentioning true will open the file in append mode
fw.write("How are You");
fw.close();
```